# Having problems with java regex

Tags: java, regex

I have the following regex:

```
/[-A-Z]{4}\d{2}/[0-9A-F]{8}-[0-9A-F]{4}-[0-9A-F]{4}-[0-9A-F]{4}-[0-9A-F]{12}.png
```

Basically I want to check for strings of the basic type

```
ABCD12/<here_is_a_random_uuid_as_a_string>.png
```

The UUID (which is in UPPER CASE) checking works fine, but now let's take a look at a special case. I want to accept strings like this

```
--CD12/...
AB--12/...
```

but NOT like this:

```
A--D12/...
```

But I can not get the first part of the regex right. Basically I need to check for either two digits or two `-`after each other twice.

For my understanding `[-A-Z]{4}` means "either - or something between A - Z with a length of 4". So why doesn't my pattern work?

EDIT:
This answer was posted within the comments and it works:

```
(?mi)^(?:--[A-Z]{2}|[A-Z]{2}(?:--|[A-Z]{2}))\d{2}/[0-9A-F]{8}(?:-[0-9A-F]{4}){3}-[0-9A-F]{12}\.png$
```

Can somebody explain to me what `(?mi)` and what `(?:...)` means? The normal `?` means 0 or 1 time, but what is the `:` for?

EDIT 2:
Just for those how might have a similar problem and do not want to read all of those regexes ;)
I slightly modified an answer to also accept patterns like `----12`. The end result:

```
"^/(?:--[A-Z]{2}|-{4}|[A-Z]{2}(?:--|[A-Z]{2}))\\d{2}/[0-9A-F]{8}(?:-[0-9A-F]{4}){3}-[0-9A-F]{12}\\.png$"
```

It works like a charm.

Comment: Please check [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/h1PEyw/4) where I added `(?![^/]*(?<![A-Z])[A-Z]--)` at the start or [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/h1PEyw/3) where I replaced `[-A-Z]{4}` with ``(?:[A-Z]{2}--|--[A-Z]{2})``

Comment: Your regex is not good for a valid UUID like "3d56bada-0373-4cf8-bd61-eeca1a606bc7"

Comment: Is your requirement that if hyphens appear at all, either the first and second characters must be hyphens or the third and fourth characters must be hyphens?

Comment: Without using any lookaahead/lookbehind it can be this: `(?mi)^(?:--[A-Z]{2}|[A-Z]{2}(?:--|[A-Z]{2}))\d{2}/[0-9A-F]{8}(?:-[0-9A-F]{4}){3}-[0-9A-F]{12}\.png$`

Comment: @jrook thanks, I have an upper case string of the uuid. Added that detail to the description

Comment: @VGR Either the first two are dashes OR the first two are digits. But it may not something like `1-` or `-1` for positions 1,2 and 3,4

Comment: Are `56--XY/...` and `AB12--/..` also valid?

Comment: No. The last two are digits. Just look at the first four values. Some examples: AB-- valid. FH-- valid, --AS valid, --YO valid. NOT VALID: -AB- or A--B or whatever letter you want. The regex of @anubhava is working. But what is `(?mi)` and what is `?:` ? I only know `?`which means 0 or 1 time, but what for is the `:` ?

Comment: Did you mean to say “Either the first two are dashes or the first two are letters and the next two are dashes”?  Because in `AB--12/`, the first two characters are not digits.

Comment: You may ignore `(?mi)` for now. `i` is for ignore case and `m` is for MULTILINE and `(?:...)` is for non-capture group.

Comment: @F_Schmidt `\p{Lu}` is 6 characters long and `[A-Z]` is 5 characters long. `\p{Lu}` matches `Ć`, and it might not be desired behavior.

Comment: You are right @RyszardCzech, thanks! I posted the final result that I am now using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `[-A-Z]{4}` matches any four occurrences of an uppercase ASCII letter or `-`, so it can also match `----`, `A---`, `---B`, `-B--`, etc.

You want to make sure that if there are hyphens, they come after or before two letters:

```
(?:[A-Z]{2}--|--[A-Z]{2}|[A-Z]{4})
```

It means:

- `(?:` - start of a non-capturing group:

  - `[A-Z]{2}--` - two uppercase ASCII letters and then `--`
  - `|` - or
  - `--[A-Z]{2}` - `--` and then any two uppercase ASCII letters
  - `|` - or
  - `[A-Z]{4}` - any four uppercase ASCII letters
- `)` - end of the non-capturing group.

The full pattern:

```
(?:[A-Z]{2}--|--[A-Z]{2}|[A-Z]{4})\d{2}/[0-9A-F]{8}-[0-9A-F]{4}-[0-9A-F]{4}-[0-9A-F]{4}-[0-9A-F]{12}\.png
```

To force the entire string match, add `^` (start of string) and `$` (end of string) anchors:

```
^(?:[A-Z]{2}--|--[A-Z]{2}|[A-Z]{4})\d{2}/[0-9A-F]{8}-[0-9A-F]{4}-[0-9A-F]{4}-[0-9A-F]{4}-[0-9A-F]{12}\.png$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/h1PEyw/5)

Note the `.` matches any char, to match a literal dot, you should escape it.

Comment: @F_Schmidt Your pattern matches `A--B12/ABCD1234-ABCD-1234-1234-ABC123ABC123.png`, see [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hjDvUu/1).

Answer (score 2):

You may use this regex for your cases:

```
^(?:--[A-Z]{2}|[A-Z]{2}(?:--|[A-Z]{2}))\d{2}/[0-9A-F]{8}(?:-[0-9A-F]{4}){3}-[0-9A-F]{12}\.png$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Vs0rU6/1)

Details about first part:

- `^`: Start
- `(?:`: Start non-capture group

  - `--[A-Z]{2}`: Match `--` followed by 2 letters
  - `|`: OR
  - `[A-Z]{2}`: Match 2 letters
  - `(?:--|[A-Z]{2})`: Match `--` OR 2 letters
- `)`: End non-capture group

btw `(?:...)` is non-capture group.